# Material UI + Next JS 13 - Styles issues in Prod

Tags: javascript, build, material-ui, next.js13

- My Application with MUI in **DEV** has one custom design
- My Application with MUI in **Prod** has no custom design

Should I make something different?
Is missing some extra configuration?

Sample of something that is not working:

```
       <Typography className={styles.customStyle} component="h1">
          {t("Translation")}
        </Typography>
```

The `className={styles.customStyle}` is totally ignored in **Prod**
This works fine in **DEV**.

---

My configuration

- **node v19.0.0**
- **Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.11.1",
    "@next/font": "13.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^18.13.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "country-flag-icons": "^1.5.5",
    "eslint": "8.29.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.1.1",
    "html-entities": "^2.3.3",
    "i18next": "^22.4.6",
    "json5": "^1.0.2",
    "next": "^13.1.1",
    "next-translate": "^1.6.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.57.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  }
}
```

- **next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FIXED:

After reading this article: https://blog.logrocket.com/getting-started-with-mui-and-next-js/

I saw that it was missing added `<CacheProvider />`.
So after that, the style custom works fine.

**SOLUTION:**

First, create a new file in the `utils` directory called `createEmotionCache.js`.

```
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";

export default function createEmotionCache() {
 return createCache({ key: "css", prepend: true });
}
```

After go to the `_app.js` or `page.js` (if using LAYOUT RFC)

```
....
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";

const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

function MyApp({
 Component,
 emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache,
 pageProps,
}) {
 return (
   <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
     <App />
   </CacheProvider>
 );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Thanks it.

Comment: You can solve a question by accepting the answer (even your own) but don't edit the post title

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works, but not effective for performance.
I tested in Chrome performance and its slower then other method for 1 second, because recall css again.

This image bellow FCP after 0,5sec
[image: Without cache provide]

But if we will try your solution we will get 1.5 in my situation (in all cases it will slower)
[image: CacheProvider solution]

I recommend to use **StyledEngineProvider** as in docs mui https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order-3
In my case it works well
Just try

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      {/* Your component tree. Now you can override Material UI's styles. */}
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```